# Why do my html select options not update when the user submits input?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working in apps script to build a scheduling assistant that draws data from and updates a google sheet. Essentially when the user wants to make an appointment an html sidebar opens. When the side bar opens the dropdown shows the correct options (available appointments based on values in the google sheet) however, once the selection has been made and the add appointment button clicked I want the dropdown to update its' options if the appointment slot is no longer available (in case the user wants to add more than one appointment per sitting, ideally not having to close the sidebar to make multiple appointments). Thanks for any help you can provide.

What I have tried:

1. Adding the loadAppt() functions to onclick for the button.
2. Adding the same code that originally populates the dropdown to the function that gets run when the addCustomerAppt button is clicked.
3. Closing the sidebar when the addCustomerAppt button is clicked
4. Refreshing the sidebar when the addCustomerAppt button is clicked

My code:

`

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Customer')
      .addItem('Add', 'addCustomer')
      .addToUi();
}

//function that displays a user input form. Used to enter customer information
function addCustomer() {
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = active.getSheetByName('Customer Data');
  if (ss) {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('testground').setTitle('Add Customer');//change to user
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .showSidebar(html);
  }
  else {
    ss = active.insertSheet();
    ss.setName('Customer Data');
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('testground').setTitle('Add Customer');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .showSidebar(html);
    var header = ['Date Time', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Student'];
    var range = ss.getRange("A1:F1");
    range.setValues([header]).setFontWeight('bold').setBackground('cyan').setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
  }
  
}


//function to calculate available appointments by date and time. 
//adds user friendly formatting depending on availability of appointment.
function calcAvailable() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("E2").setFormula("=C2 - D2");

  //get the last row to dynamically input the formula above
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  //why do I have to subtract one from last row? I don't seem to understand getLastRow()
  var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(2, 5, lastRow - 1);
  ss.getRange("E2").copyTo(fillDownRange);

  //set rules for background colors
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenNumberGreaterThan(0)
    .setBackground("#90ee90")
    .setRanges([fillDownRange])
    .build();
  var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenNumberLessThanOrEqualTo(0)
    .setBackground("#ffcccb")
    .setRanges([fillDownRange])
    .build();
var rules = ss.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(rule);
rules.push(rule2);
ss.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

**function newAppointment(dateTime, first, last, email, phone) {
  var values = [dateTime, first, last, email, phone];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Customer Data');
  sheet.appendRow(values);

  //this section updates the available column after the apoinment is made
  var apptSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Appointment View');
  var lastRow = apptSheet.getLastRow();
  var dataArray = apptSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 2).getDisplayValues();
  //must use split here as the date and time are passed as a single string;
  var dtgArray = dateTime.split(',');
  
  dataArray.forEach(function(item, index) {
      
      if(item[0] == dtgArray[0] && item[1] == dtgArray[1]) {
      var updateCol = apptSheet.getRange(index + 2, 4, 1, 1);
      var currentAppt = updateCol.getValue();
      updateCol.setValue(currentAppt += 1); 
      }
  });

}**

function getList() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var apptSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Appointment View');
  var lastRow = apptSheet.getLastRow();
  //apps script cannot return any date object. Must use getDisplayValues() below and post process.
  //var dataArray = apptSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 2).getDisplayValues();
  var dataArray = apptSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 5).getDisplayValues();
  var filterArr = dataArray.filter(apptBlock => apptBlock[4] > 0);
  var listArr = [];
  filterArr.forEach(function (block) {
    listArr.push([block[0], block[1]]);

  })
  
  return listArr;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    
    <script>
      **function addCustomerAppt() {
        //Add customer info from the form
        var dateTime = document.getElementById('dateTime').value;
        //var time = document.getElementById('time').value;
        var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
        //pass the above variables to the app script function
        google.script.run.newAppointment(dateTime, firstName, lastName, email, phone);
        
      }**


      //script to load appt into the dropdown menu. Limits choices to what is in appointment spreadsheet
      **function loadAppt() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
        {
        var apptSelect = document.getElementById("dateTime");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = "";
        option.text = "";
        apptSelect.appendChild(option); 

        ar.forEach(function(item, index){
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = [item[0], item[1]];
          option.text = [item[0], item[1]];
          apptSelect.appendChild(option);
        });
        }).getList();
      };**
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <p>
        **<label for="dateTime">Enter Appointment Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <select id="dateTime" name="dateTime"></select>
      </p>
      <script>loadAppt();</script>**
      <p>
        <label for="firstName">Enter First Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="lastName">Enter Last Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="email">Enter Customer Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="phone">Enter Customer Phone:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
      </p>
      **<p>
        <label for="addCustomerAppt"></label>
        <input type="button" value="Add Customer" onclick="addCustomerAppt()">
      </p>**
      
  </body>
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details on what options should be updated, with what information should they be updated, and when should they be updated? Please provide server-side code if necessary for reproducing this. More in general, please consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Regarding what needs to be updated there is a column in the Google sheet that shows a number of available appointments for that particular time slot. When a customer is added that number is decremented. When it reaches 0 the idea is to remove that time slot option (date and time) from the html dropdown list of available options to the user. Basically assisting with not overbooking that slot. Will do on the minimal reproducible example in the future, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your front-end function **addCustomerAppt** calls back-end function **newAppointment**.

Google Apps Script function **newAppointment** can return the result, updated available slots, after adding a new one. Try calculating that result and passing it as a function return value.

You can use that result on the front end. Log it to the console in your tests, then use it to repopulate the HTML select element.

Comment: So I implemented this and I wound up adding a line that cleared the dropdown  prior to appending the new list and it functioned as intended. Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction. Take care.